# Can elliptic curve groups be used for commutative encryption?

Tags: elliptic-curves, mental-poker

In trying to implement mental poker, can all players agree on a standard set of 52 points on the curve corresponding to each card, and then to "encrypt" a card you just multiply it by a scalar which is your encryption key? (and to decrypt, multiply by the scalar's inverse modulo the group size)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by commutative in this context?

Comment: Ek(Ej(X)) = Ej(Ek(X)) where Ek(X) is encryted versions of X under key K. It's from the mental poker paper Shamir Rivest and Adleman. They call this property "commutativity of encryption".

Answer (score 2):

This works, as long as the 52 points are chosen such that their discrete logs w.r.t. each other are unknowable.

E.g. if $5♠$ is point $P$, and $6♦$ is point $Q$, and your encryption scalar is $x$, then you could encrypt $5♠$ using $P' = xP$. Now, if you know $y=P/Q$, then you could pretend you had encrypted $6♦$ instead of $5♠$ by declaring your encryption key as $z=xy$, because $z^{-1}P'=(xy)^{-1}P'=(xP/Q)^{-1}P'=(xP/Q)^{-1}xP=(Q/xP)xP=Q$

I'd recommend you use a [hash-to-curve](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-irtf-cfrg-hash-to-curve/) method to produce the point $P$ by hashing the string $5♠$. The discrete logs of hash-to-curve points with respect to other curve points are unknowable.

In contrast, it would be catastrophic if you'd chosen points such that each point was a base point $G$ added to itself between 1 and 52 times, depending on the card.

Note that you would need to use a different encryption key every time you encrypt a card, to ensure that the same card encrypted twice (during different rounds) does not produce the same encrypted point each time.